# Custom error in Spring Boot Microservices Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, error-handling, microservices, openapi

I'm making a car sharing platform in Java Spring boot. Im using open api files to define my paths and objects. I want to implement a way to have a custom error message shown when a user searched on id is not found.

I have tried everything but my method expects an ApiUser, like defined in my openapi file. When it is succesfull, I indeed want to return an ApiUser but when there is an error I want to return a custom error message a throw in my service. I cannot change the return type of the method, it needs to stay like how it is now.

This is my custom error:

```
package com.example.userservice.domain.user;

public class UserException extends RuntimeException{

    public UserException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

}
```

This is my service:

```
package com.example.userservice.domain.user;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.example.userservice.api.model.ApiUser;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Component
public class UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    private final EventSender eventSender;

    @Autowired
    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository, EventSender eventSender) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.eventSender = eventSender;
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        //System.out.println(userRepository.findAll());
        return (List<User>) userRepository.findAll();

    }

    public void createUser(ApiUser data) {
        List<User> users = (List<User>) userRepository.findAll();

        for (User user: users) {
            if (user.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(data.getName())) {
                throw new UserException("Already a user with this name");
            }
            if (user.getEmail().equalsIgnoreCase(data.getEmail())) {
                throw new UserException("Already a user with this email");
            }
        }
        User user = new User(data.getName(), data.getEmail());
        userRepository.save(user);
        eventSender.sendUserCreatedEvent(user);
    }



    public User getUserById(Long id) {
        Optional<User> userOptional = userRepository.findById(id);
        if (!userOptional.isPresent()) {
            throw new UserException("User not found with ID: " + id);
        }
        return userOptional.get();
    }

    public User validateUser(Long id) {
        Optional<User> userOptional = userRepository.findById(id);
        if (!userOptional.isPresent()) {
            throw new UserException("User not found with ID: " + id);
        }
        return userOptional.get();
    }


}
```

This is my controller with the error:

```
Incompatible types. Found: 'org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String>', required: 'org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.example.userservice.api.model.ApiUser>'
```

```
package com.example.userservice.web;

import com.example.userservice.api.model.ApiCar;
import com.example.userservice.api.model.ApiUsers;
import com.example.userservice.domain.car.Car;
import com.example.userservice.domain.user.User;
import com.example.userservice.domain.user.UserException;
import com.example.userservice.domain.user.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.example.userservice.api.UserApiDelegate;
import com.example.userservice.api.model.ApiUser;

import java.util.List;

@Component
public class UserController implements UserApiDelegate {

    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<String> createUser(ApiUser data) {
        try {
            userService.createUser(data);
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Successfully created user");
        } catch (UserException e) {
            return ResponseEntity
                    .status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
                    .body("Error creating user: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<ApiUser> getUserById(Long userID) {
        try {
            User user = userService.getUserById(userID);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(toDto(user));
        } catch (UserException e) {
            return ResponseEntity
                    .status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
                    .body("Error creating user: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<ApiUsers> getUsers() {
        ApiUsers apiUsers = new ApiUsers();
        List<User> users = userService.getUsers();

        for (User user : users) {
            apiUsers.add(toDto(user));
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(apiUsers);
    }

    private ApiUser toDto(User user) {
        ApiUser apiUser = new ApiUser();
        apiUser.setName(user.getName());
        apiUser.setUserID(user.getUserID());
        apiUser.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        if (user.getCar() != null) {
            apiUser.setCar(toApiCarDto(user.getCar()));
        }
        return apiUser;
    }

    public static ApiCar toApiCarDto(Car car) {

        ApiCar apiCar = new ApiCar();
        apiCar.setCarID(car.getCarID());
        apiCar.setBrand(car.getBrand());
        apiCar.setModel(car.getModel());
        apiCar.setPricePerHour(car.getPricePerHour());
        apiCar.setLocation(car.getLocation());

        return apiCar;
    }




}
```

And this is my openapi file:

```
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: User Service
  description: API for User Management
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  /api/v1/user:
    post:
      tags:
        - User
      description: Create a new user
      operationId: createUser
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: "#/components/schemas/ApiUser"
      responses:
        "200":
          description: User successfully created
          content:
            text/plain:
              schema:
                type: string
                example: "Successfully created user"
        "400":
          description: Bad Request - Invalid input or user already exists
          content:
            text/plain:
              schema:
                type: string
                example: "Error creating user: [error details]"
        "500":
          description: Internal Error
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/ApiError"
    get:
      tags:
        - User
      description: Retrieve all users
      operationId: getUsers
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful operation
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/ApiUsers'
        "500":
          description: Internal Error
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/ApiError"
  /api/v1/user/{userID}:
    get:
      tags:
        - User
      description: Retrieve a user by their ID
      operationId: getUserById
      parameters:
        - name: userID
          in: path
          required: true
          description: Unique identifier of the user
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int64
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful operation
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/ApiUser'
        "500":
          description: Internal Error
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/ApiError"
components:
  schemas:
    ApiUsers:
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/ApiUser'
    ApiUser:
      type: object
      properties:
        userID:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        name:
          type: string
        email:
          type: string
        car:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/ApiCar'
    ApiCar:
      type: object
      properties:
        carID:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        brand:
          type: string
        model:
          type: string
        pricePerHour:
          type: number
          format: double
        location:
          type: string
    UserCreatedEvent:
      type: object
      properties:
        user:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/ApiUser'
    ApiError:
      type: object
      properties:
        code:
          type: string
          description: "Functional code specifying the error"
          example: "2300"
        message:
          type: string
          description: "Brief explanation about the error, for more information consult the User Service team"
    ValidateUserCommand:
      type: object
      properties:
        reservationID:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        userID:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        name:
          type: string
        email:
          type: string
    UserValidatedEvent:
      type: object
      properties:
        reservationID:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        userID:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        name:
          type: string
        email:
          type: string
```

Comment: `getUserById` is defined to return `ResponseEntity<ApiUser>`, but the error path is attempting to set the ResponseEntity body to a String, which is not an `ApiUser`.

Comment: Yes I know, but what I want to know is if there is a way to work around that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to return a `ResponseEntity<String>` while you actually want to return `ResponseEntity<Void>`. Since you are creating a new User, you do not want to return a response body, therefore your response body should be empty.

So, your method should look like this:

```
@Override
public ResponseEntity<Void> createUser(ApiUser data) {
        userService.createUser(data);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).build();
}
```

For POST requests where you create new entities, you should be using 201 CREATED instead of 200 OK.

Create your custom exception like so:

```
package com.example.userservice.domain.user;

public class UserException extends ResponseStatusException {

public UserException(String reason) {
    super(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, message);

   }
}
```

When you extend this `ResponseStatusException` with custom `HttpStatus`, you can throw it with your specified message in your service layer and it will respond with your custom HTTP status, no need to catch them afterwards since Spring responds with this exception afterwards.

Also other small things to mention:

1. For mapping entities to your custom DTOs, you can use annotation processor like [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/). This will generate mappings for your entities, therefore saving you from the custom bloat code you make. Also you should do this in the service layer instead where all the business logic is happening.
2. I highly recommend using [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/), which lets you generate getters, setters, constructors and such for your classes, which is also generated by the annotation processing, saving you from other lots of bloat code. For example:

   ```
   @Component
   @RequiredArgsConstructor
   public class UserController implements UserApiDelegate {

   private final UserService userService;
   ```

will create the custom constructor for you with the `UserService` parameter.